# Django & Tagulous - Displaying Posts from two filters within my queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am wanting to display Posts based on two filters (Date Posted - Which I have already got working) but I wanted to also display posts based on which Tagulous tags are stored as apart of the currently logged in user's meta data.

For example, if User A has the tag "Summer" stored as apart of their metadata, the logged in user would only see posts relating to the "Summer" tag and wouldn't see any Posts which have been created under any other tags such as "Autumn, Winter, or Spring."

I've made a basic start with implementing in the Tagulous filters, but not too sure which direction to go in from here.

```
class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'core/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = PAGINATION_COUNT

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        all_users = []
        data_counter = Post.objects.values('author')\
            .annotate(author_count=Count('author'))\
            .order_by('-author_count')[:6]
        
        # Tagulous objects
        getseason = Season.objects.filter(season='winter')
        user_tag = Season.tag_model.objects.filter(season__owner=request.user)

        for aux in data_counter:
            all_users.append(User.objects.filter(pk=aux['author']).first())
    
        data['preference'] = Preference.objects.all()
    
        data['all_users'] = all_users
        print(all_users, file=sys.stderr)
        return data

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        qs = Follow.objects.filter(user=user)
        follows = [user]
        for obj in qs:
            follows.append(obj.follow_user)
        return Post.objects.filter(author__in=follows).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Any assistance or guidance would be most appreciated! :-)

Comment: I think this is what are you looking for https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: also dont use for loop in get_queryset. You should write the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the answer was more simpler than what I thought, I just needed to add another .filter to my query   `return Post.objects.filter(author__in=follows).filter(season='1').order_by('-date_posted')`

and it worked! (I'm now seeing all posts where the user has the tag "Summer" stored within the metadata within their account. My only challenge now, is trying to find a way of pulling all the tags which the user follows, rather than manually specifying the "ID" number of their chosen tag category.

I need to find a way of pulling the existing tags the user already follows from their metadata and then returning posts for the tags which they have stored on their account.